# How can I log the commands magit uses for values?

Tags: magit

I'm bringing up a new machine and some operations are very slow. I'd like to re-run the commands magit is sending in a normal shell so I can use perf to see where time is being spent. magit-git-debug only logs output of failed commands and I don't really want the output but just the commands themselves.

Comment: I wrote some code in [#3096](https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/3096) to measure git calls and list them in org table format, is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @npostavs do you reckon it's worth getting cleaned up and merged into magit upstream?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, I haven't had much use for it since.

Answer (score 1):

As @npostavs mentioned in a comment, he wrote [some advise](https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/3096) that can be used to do so.

This is useful for debugging performance issues, but I don't think it should be added to Magit. But if someone gets around to improve upon it, then please add it to the list of [code snippets](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Code-snippets) on the wiki.